# how logical addresses are genearted in segmented memory management

Tags: operating-system

In segmented memory management the logical address is a pair (segment number, offset) which is then translated to physical address using segment table. I dont understand how this logical address is generated from instruction like JMP some_address.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several different methods employed to implement segmented memory management. The entire concept of using segments was obsolete by the 1980's and only survived longer in legacy and poorly designed processors.

Normally, this is NOT correct:

> In segmented memory management the logical address is a pair

In segmented memory, the address is a composed of an offset and a base location specified by a register.